# How to I save some data into userStorage in the Java/Kotlin Client Library for Actions on Google

Tags: kotlin, actions-on-google

I am trying to save some info in the userStorage in Kotlin

In javascript, I did the following

```
exports.saveFloor = (conv, floor) => {
conv.user.storage.floor = floor;
```

}

here is the client [library](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-java)

Answer (score 1):

From [Name Psychic](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-name-psychic-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/MyActionsApp.java):

```
@ForIntent("request_name_permission")
public ActionResponse requestNamePermission(ActionRequest request) {
  ResponseBuilder response = getResponseBuilder(request);

  String requestedPermission = ConstantsKt.PERMISSION_NAME;

  response.getConversationData().put(DATA_KEY_REQUESTED_PERMISSION, requestedPermission);

  String storageKey = STORAGE_KEY_NAME;

  if (!request.getUserStorage().containsKey(storageKey)) {
    Permission permission =
        new Permission()
          .setContext(formatResponse("permission_reason"))
          .setPermissions(new String[] {requestedPermission});
    response.add("PLACEHOLDER_FOR_PERMISSION");
    response.add(permission);
  } else {
    String name = (String) request.getUserStorage().get(storageKey);
    response.add(formatResponse("say_name", name));
    response.endConversation();
  }

  return response.build();
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I m wrong, isn't this demonstrating how to retrieve a value from the UserStorage instead of saving it ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the snippet I was looking for is

```
 Map<String, Object> storage = response.getUserStorage();

String requestedPermission =
    (String) request.getConversationData().get(DATA_KEY_REQUESTED_PERMISSION);
if (requestedPermission.equals(ConstantsKt.PERMISSION_NAME)) {
  String name = request.getUser().getProfile().getDisplayName();
  storage.put(STORAGE_KEY_NAME, name);
  response.add(formatResponse("say_name", name));
  response.endConversation();
  return response.build();
} 
if (requestedPermission.equals(ConstantsKt.PERMISSION_DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
  String location = request.getDevice().getLocation().getCity();
  storage.put(STORAGE_KEY_LOCATION, location);
  showLocationOnScreen(request, response);
  return response.build();
}
```

The equivalent of my javascript code into Kotlin would be

```
fun saveFloor(request: ActionRequest, floor: String) {
    val response = getResponseBuilder(request)
    val storage = response.userStorage as MutableMap

    storage["floor"] = floor
}
```

Cheers to [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491707/nick-felker) for pointing me in the right direction